# Mapbox tooltips being disabled by code

Tags: javascript, mapbox, tilemill

Can anyone see what in this code is preventing the tooltips in my map from functioning?  Ie they function in normal map but not when I add the layers to this map with a toggle button.  I assume it's something with the onclick function, but can't figure it out specifically, and what a workaround might be.

Thank you

```
<style>
.menu-ui {
  background:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;left:10px;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:120px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }
  .menu-ui a {
    font-size:13px;
    color:#404040;
    display:block;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    text-align:center;
    }
    .menu-ui a:first-child {
      border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
      }
    .menu-ui a:last-child {
      border:none;
      border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
      }
    .menu-ui a:hover {
      background:#f8f8f8;
      color:#404040;
      }
    .menu-ui a.active {
      background:#3887BE;
      color:#FFF;
      }
      .menu-ui a.active:hover {
        background:#3074a4;
        }
</style>
<nav id='menu-ui' class='menu-ui'></nav>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([10.8229,-84.2116], 12);
var layers = document.getElementById('menu-ui');

addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('XXXX.XXXX'), 'Photo Points', 4);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('XXXX.XXXX'), 'River KMs', 3);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('XXXX.XXXXX'), 'December 2013 (0.5m)', 2);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('XXXXXX.XXXXXX'), 'February 2014 (1.5m)', 1);


function addLayer(layer, name, zIndex) {
    layer
        .setZIndex(zIndex)
        .addTo(map);

    // Create a simple layer switcher that
    // toggles layers on and off.
    var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#';
        link.className = 'active';
        link.innerHTML = name;

    link.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
            this.className = '';
        } else {
            map.addLayer(layer);
            this.className = 'active';
        }
    };

    layers.appendChild(link);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add interactivity via [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)? If so, you'll need to [add the gridLayer and gridControl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/gridlayer-gridcontrol/) to the map, not just a tileLayer.